# concatenate files including path in header - path contains spaces

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, bash-scripting, concatenation

I have to concatenate a number of files in a directory structure which contains spaces in the folder names looking like this: ./CH 0000100014/A10/11XT/11xt#001.csv

```
find . -name "*.csv" -type f -print0 | xargs -0  cat > allmycsv.txt
```

does the job, however now I need to include the information contained in the path, i.e. `CH 0000100014/A10/11XT` as a header of each inputfile to cat.

```
find . -name "*.csv" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I % sh -c 'echo %; cat %' >allmycsv.txt
```

would do the job, if I had no spaces in the path, but in my case, cat does not get along with the space in the path name. Is there a way out?

Cheers,
E

P.S. I am working on bash on OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file list in a while loop (see [BashFAQ #020](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)):

```
find . -name "*.csv" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
    echo "$file"
    cat "$file"
done >allmycsv.txt
```

Comment: You can also just use `-d ''` instead of `-d $'\0'`, which works either because `bash` special cases the empty string, or because the "first" character of the null string is the null-byte terminator (I'm not sure which).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding double quote characters around the % characters:

> sh -c 'echo **"**%**"**; cat **"**%**"** '